# how to align objects inside LinearLayout/scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an application were i am trying to align 3 textViews. These are inside a LinearLayout(vertical orientation) which is placed inside a ScrollView.

If I don't use the ScrollView and the LinearLayout I can have all three aligned to each other as one on the left of the screen, and the other 2 to the right.

But when I use the ScrollView and the LinearLayout I can only align them at the bottom and no longer to the right.

can some help me to align these three text views inside the ScrollView ?

this is the code I am using:

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="250dp" > 
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:text="one"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="two"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="three"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

i need the code to be something like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="one"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="two"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:text="three"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

Use Relative layout instead of LinearLayout. 
and don't use

android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"

in liner layout